# RewriteRule in .htacces to serve a precise file (not a URI)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this `.htaccess` in my `DocumentRoot`:

```
DirectorySlash      Off
RewriteEngine       On
RewriteRule         ^(.*)$          /views/Dispatch.php [END]
```

If I put a `Deny From All` Directive in a `.htaccess` inside `/views/`, Apache gives an HTTP403, so I assume Apache is considering `/views/Dispatch.php` as a URI to pass to other .htaccess instead of a direct server's file to serve.

Apache's `error.log` yields (with `LogLevel rewrite_module:trace8`):

```
[Tue Sep 02 09:25:01.636536 2014] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 2316:tid 1004] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 127.0.0.1:49769] 127.0.0.1 - - [127.0.0.1/sid#47a2e8][rid#12bd3b0/initial] [perdir N:/web/binaries/easy-php/14.1/data/localweb/] strip per-dir prefix: N:/web/binaries/easy-php/14.1/data/localweb/ -> 
[Tue Sep 02 09:25:01.637536 2014] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 2316:tid 1004] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 127.0.0.1:49769] 127.0.0.1 - - [127.0.0.1/sid#47a2e8][rid#12bd3b0/initial] [perdir N:/web/binaries/easy-php/14.1/data/localweb/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri ''
[Tue Sep 02 09:25:01.637536 2014] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 2316:tid 1004] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 127.0.0.1:49769] 127.0.0.1 - - [127.0.0.1/sid#47a2e8][rid#12bd3b0/initial] [perdir N:/web/binaries/easy-php/14.1/data/localweb/] rewrite '' -> '/views/Dispatch.php'
[Tue Sep 02 09:25:01.637536 2014] [rewrite:trace8] [pid 2316:tid 1004] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 127.0.0.1:49769] 127.0.0.1 - - [127.0.0.1/sid#47a2e8][rid#12bd3b0/initial] [perdir N:/web/binaries/easy-php/14.1/data/localweb/] Rule has END flag, no further rewriting for this request
[Tue Sep 02 09:25:01.637536 2014] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 2316:tid 1004] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 127.0.0.1:49769] 127.0.0.1 - - [127.0.0.1/sid#47a2e8][rid#12bd3b0/initial] [perdir N:/web/binaries/easy-php/14.1/data/localweb/] internal redirect with /views/Dispatch.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
[Tue Sep 02 09:25:01.638536 2014] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 2316:tid 1004] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 127.0.0.1:49769] 127.0.0.1 - - [127.0.0.1/sid#47a2e8][rid#12c13c0/subreq] [perdir N:/web/binaries/easy-php/14.1/data/localweb/] strip per-dir prefix: N:/web/binaries/easy-php/14.1/data/localweb/index.html -> index.html
[Tue Sep 02 09:25:01.638536 2014] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 2316:tid 1004] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 127.0.0.1:49769] 127.0.0.1 - - [127.0.0.1/sid#47a2e8][rid#12c13c0/subreq] [perdir N:/web/binaries/easy-php/14.1/data/localweb/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'index.html'
[Tue Sep 02 09:25:01.638536 2014] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 2316:tid 1004] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 127.0.0.1:49769] 127.0.0.1 - - [127.0.0.1/sid#47a2e8][rid#12c13c0/subreq] [perdir N:/web/binaries/easy-php/14.1/data/localweb/] rewrite 'index.html' -> '/views/Dispatch.php'
[Tue Sep 02 09:25:01.638536 2014] [rewrite:trace8] [pid 2316:tid 1004] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 127.0.0.1:49769] 127.0.0.1 - - [127.0.0.1/sid#47a2e8][rid#12c13c0/subreq] [perdir N:/web/binaries/easy-php/14.1/data/localweb/] Rule has END flag, no further rewriting for this request
[Tue Sep 02 09:25:01.638536 2014] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 2316:tid 1004] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 127.0.0.1:49769] 127.0.0.1 - - [127.0.0.1/sid#47a2e8][rid#12c13c0/subreq] [perdir N:/web/binaries/easy-php/14.1/data/localweb/] internal redirect with /views/Dispatch.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
[Tue Sep 02 09:25:01.638536 2014] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 2316:tid 1004] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 127.0.0.1:49769] 127.0.0.1 - - [127.0.0.1/sid#47a2e8][rid#12c13c0/subreq] [perdir N:/web/binaries/easy-php/14.1/data/localweb/] strip per-dir prefix: N:/web/binaries/easy-php/14.1/data/localweb/index.xml -> index.xml
[Tue Sep 02 09:25:01.638536 2014] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 2316:tid 1004] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 127.0.0.1:49769] 127.0.0.1 - - [127.0.0.1/sid#47a2e8][rid#12c13c0/subreq] [perdir N:/web/binaries/easy-php/14.1/data/localweb/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'index.xml'
[Tue Sep 02 09:25:01.639536 2014] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 2316:tid 1004] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 127.0.0.1:49769] 127.0.0.1 - - [127.0.0.1/sid#47a2e8][rid#12c13c0/subreq] [perdir N:/web/binaries/easy-php/14.1/data/localweb/] rewrite 'index.xml' -> '/views/Dispatch.php'
[Tue Sep 02 09:25:01.639536 2014] [rewrite:trace8] [pid 2316:tid 1004] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 127.0.0.1:49769] 127.0.0.1 - - [127.0.0.1/sid#47a2e8][rid#12c13c0/subreq] [perdir N:/web/binaries/easy-php/14.1/data/localweb/] Rule has END flag, no further rewriting for this request
[Tue Sep 02 09:25:01.639536 2014] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 2316:tid 1004] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 127.0.0.1:49769] 127.0.0.1 - - [127.0.0.1/sid#47a2e8][rid#12c13c0/subreq] [perdir N:/web/binaries/easy-php/14.1/data/localweb/] internal redirect with /views/Dispatch.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
[Tue Sep 02 09:25:01.639536 2014] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 2316:tid 1004] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 127.0.0.1:49769] 127.0.0.1 - - [127.0.0.1/sid#47a2e8][rid#12c13c0/subreq] [perdir N:/web/binaries/easy-php/14.1/data/localweb/] strip per-dir prefix: N:/web/binaries/easy-php/14.1/data/localweb/index.php -> index.php
[Tue Sep 02 09:25:01.639536 2014] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 2316:tid 1004] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 127.0.0.1:49769] 127.0.0.1 - - [127.0.0.1/sid#47a2e8][rid#12c13c0/subreq] [perdir N:/web/binaries/easy-php/14.1/data/localweb/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'index.php'
[Tue Sep 02 09:25:01.639536 2014] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 2316:tid 1004] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 127.0.0.1:49769] 127.0.0.1 - - [127.0.0.1/sid#47a2e8][rid#12c13c0/subreq] [perdir N:/web/binaries/easy-php/14.1/data/localweb/] rewrite 'index.php' -> '/views/Dispatch.php'
[Tue Sep 02 09:25:01.639536 2014] [rewrite:trace8] [pid 2316:tid 1004] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 127.0.0.1:49769] 127.0.0.1 - - [127.0.0.1/sid#47a2e8][rid#12c13c0/subreq] [perdir N:/web/binaries/easy-php/14.1/data/localweb/] Rule has END flag, no further rewriting for this request
[Tue Sep 02 09:25:01.639536 2014] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 2316:tid 1004] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 127.0.0.1:49769] 127.0.0.1 - - [127.0.0.1/sid#47a2e8][rid#12c13c0/subreq] [perdir N:/web/binaries/easy-php/14.1/data/localweb/] internal redirect with /views/Dispatch.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
[Tue Sep 02 09:25:01.639536 2014] [access_compat:error] [pid 2316:tid 1004] [client 127.0.0.1:49769] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: N:/web/binaries/easy-php/14.1/data/localweb/views/Dispatch.php
```

**How do I tell Apache (`2.4.7`) to serve `/views/Dispatch.php` file (from server's file system) instead of considering it as a URI?**

Comment: Do you get any error messages in the error log? Have you enabled logging for mod-rewrite?

Comment: You can only use `[END]` if the version of your web server is 2.4+ if its not that would fail. Also the file must be inside your domain documentroot, otherwise it will not be able to read it. For example, for `/views/Dispatch.php` it will try to find the file at documentroot+`/views/Dispatch.php`.

Comment: @MrTux Log content added

Comment: @Prix Apache's version added.

Comment: @Xenos [its been reported that version below 2.4.9 have a bug that lead all redirects to the defined index page, you will have to upgrade it to 2.4.9 or above.](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53929#c10)